# Angular js install external library failed to instantiate module npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm, chart.js

In my AngularJS project I tried to add the external library ,example chart.js.
So I started with command to add the new package in node_modules:

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

During download I see this warning:

> `-- chart.js@3.5.0
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7
> (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
> fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> {"os":"w"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
> DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
> (node_modules\karma\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm
> WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
> fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> {"os":"w"win32","arch":"x64"})

Despite the warning I found the chart.js in my node_modules folder.

After that, as explained in the guide I add in my controller the reference to the new module:

```
angular
  .module('myportal',['chart.js'])
  .controller(
    'PortalController',
      [
      '$scope',function($scope){
      // other functions
```

But when I tried to start the web app I see this errors that stop the loading of the application:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module chart.js due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'chart.js' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=chart.js
    at http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:1986:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:1910:38)
    at module (http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:1984:14)
    at http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:4390:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:336:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:4374:5)
    at http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:4391:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:336:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3001/lib/angular/angular.js:4374:5)
```

Have I omitted something in my controller or some other configuration file? Or does it depend on something else that I'm forgetting?(I m using grunt and I don't add script tag with path in index.html) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding the location of the chart.js into your index.html.

```
<script src='node_modules/chartjs/chartjs.js'></script>
```

The above is a guess at the path for the file. npm will install it to your location directory but AngularJS doesn't know where that file is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I would avoid to adding <script> in index.html. Are there other solutions?